# Webpack - empty target folder after building my application

Tags: webpack

I run `npm run build` from bash and the target folder (`lib`) doesn't contain any files.

Here is my webpack.config-build.js file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");
const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

module.exports = {
    entry: [path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js')],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            use: ['babel-loader'],
            include: path.join(__dirname, '/src')
        }]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/lib')
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/react\/addons/),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/react\/lib\/ReactContext/),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/react\/lib\/ExecutionEnvironment/)
    ],
    target: 'node'
};
```

Here is the output after running the command (no errors):

```
Hash: 9e969aec2448315372a9
Version: webpack 2.2.1 
Time: 3121ms
Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names 
index.js  2.67 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main   
[15] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]  
[121] ./~/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js 40 kB {0} [built]  
[123] ./~/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js 42.7 kB {0} [built]  
[140] ./~/intl-messageformat/index.js 553 bytes {0} [built]  
[213] ./src/index.js 2.43 kB {0} [built]  
[238] ./~/enzyme/build/index.js 973 bytes {0} [built]  
[239] ./~/enzyme/build/mount.js 549 bytes {0} [built]  
[240] ./~/enzyme/build/render.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]  
[241] ./~/enzyme/build/shallow.js 544 bytes {0} [built]  
[264] ./~/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js 6.94 kB {0} [optional] [built]  
[272] ./~/intl-format-cache/index.js 110 bytes {0} [built]  
[293] ./~/jsonfile/index.js 3.13 kB {0} [built]  
[470] ./~/react-intl/lib/index.es.js 55 kB {0} [built]  
[471] ./~/react-intl/locale-data/index.js 290 kB {0} [built]  
[494] multi ./src/index.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 480 hidden modules
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set the output path to `/lib`, that is the root of your file system, not the `lib` in your current directory. The reason for that is [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) treats `/lib` as an absolute path. That would usually throw a permission denied error unless you're running it as root. Change your output path to:

```
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib')
```